# Problem: How many 'timetables' can be created for visiting 8 different lectures without time clashes?

Tags: statistics, discrete-mathematics, problem-solving

Apologies for the poorly worded question but it really requires more explanation than can be done with one line.
I have a statistics problem, or rather, a timetabling problem that I feel can be solved using mathematical methods.

Suppose you want to visit 8 different lectures in one day.
Some run many times in the day, others less frequently.
You want to visit all 8 in one day, leaving a gap of at least 5 minutes between lectures to travel to the next one. Each lecture lasts 30 minutes.

How many unique timetables can be created?

How many ways can all 8 lectures be arranged on a calendar for a single day such that there are no clashes, no lectures overlap and there is always 5 minutes between each lecture?

The lecture timings data is below.

> Lecture 1 runs at 10:00, 12:45, 14:15.
>
> Lecture 2 runs at 12:30, 14:45, 10:15, 13:15.
>
> Lecture 3 runs at 11:45, 14:00.
>
> Lecture 4 runs at 11:15, 12:00, 13:30.
>
> Lecture 8 runs at 09:30, 11:30, 13:45, 14:45, 15:30.
>
> Lecture 5 runs at 09:45, 10:25, 12:05, 12:55, 14:35, 15:25.
>
> Lecture 6 runs at 11:15, 13:45.
>
> Lecture 7 runs at 10:20, 11:20, 12:50, 15:20.

I figure possibly a very large Venn diagram could be used. I improvised a timeline-like chart on paper and manually found 1 solution, which is below.

> Lecture 5 at 9:45 to 10:15
>
> Lecture 7 at 10:20 to 10:50
>
> Lecture 6 at 11:15 to 11:45
>
> Lecture 4 at 12:00 to 12:30
>
> Lecture 1 at 12:45 to 13:15
>
> Lecture 3 at 14:00 to 14:30
>
> Lecture 2 at 14:45 to 15:15
>
> Lecture 8 at 15:30 to 16:00

How can I calculate if this is the only solution? Can I calculate the number of solutions? Can I visualise the data and easily pick out solutions?

I'm very interested in this problem, and I hope maybe somebody on here can assist or give suggestions on how I could solve this.

Thanks.

Comment: Your solution doesn't seem to fit the data.  There is no lecture 5 at 9:45, and no lecture 7 at 10:20.  I didn't check the others.

Comment: @saulspatz Ah, sorry, I messed up writing them down from the paper, there were two different orders. It’s correct now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my calculations there are $4$ possible schedules:

```
['12:45', '14:45', '14:0', '12:0', '9:45', '11:15', '10:20', '15:30']
['12:45', '14:45', '14:0', '12:0', '10:25', '11:15', '15:20', '9:30']
['12:45', '14:45', '14:0', '12:0', '15:25', '11:15', '10:20', '9:30']
['12:45', '10:15', '14:0', '12:0', '14:35', '11:15', '15:20', '9:30']
```

I didn't take the trouble to format the output nicely, I'm afraid.  The interpretation of the first schedule is:

- attend lecture 1 at 12:45
- attend lecture 2 at 14:25
- attend lecture 3 at 14:00
- and so on

I assumed that in you data, the last lecture for lecture 1 is at 14:15 rather than and 2:15 and the last lecture for lecture 2 is at 13:15.

There are so few possibilities that my script just takes the cartesian product of all possible lectures, and checks which ones are admissible.

**EDIT**

Here's the script as you requested, but it's very simple-minded.

```
from itertools import product

def format(t):
    return '%s:%s'% divmod(t,60)

lecture = 9*[None]
lecture[1] = [(10,00), (12,45), (14,15)]
lecture[2] = [(12,30), (14,45), (10,15), (13,15)]
lecture[3] = [(11,45), (14,00)]
lecture[4]= [(11,15), (12,00), (13,30)]
lecture[8] = [(9,30), (11,30), (13,45), (14,45), (15,30)]
lecture[5] =  [(9,45), (10,25), (12,5), (12,55), (14,35), (15,25)]
lecture[6] = [(11,15), (13,45)]
lecture[7] = [(10,20), (11,20), (12,50), (15,20)]

for i in range(1,9):
    for idx, s in enumerate(lecture[i]):
        lecture[i][idx] = 60*s[0]+s[1]

schedules = []
for sched in product(*lecture[1:]):
    times = sorted(sched)
    times = zip(times, times[1:])
    if all(t[1]-t[0]>=35 for t in times):
        schedules.append(sched)

for sched in schedules: 
    print(list(map(format,sched)))
```

Comment: This is fantastic, thanks so much. Could I see the script, if you don’t mind?

Comment: You're welcome.  I posted the script.